# Organizing AngularJS applications

Tags: angularjs

I feel like there is relatively little documentation on the "best practices" of how one should go about organizing `AngularJS` code. For example, in many of my web pages, i.e.

- index.php
- profile.php
- editprofile.php

There are often many factories and methods that I need repeated. For example, `profile.php`,, `editprofile.php`, and `index.php` all need the factory `userDropdown` (to get the top navbar dropdown menu). However, some of them need "modified versions of factories". For example:

- index.php needs a way to get all the users and their information
- profile.php needs a way to get some users information
- editProfile.php needs a way to get only one user information

What I mean is that (and the above was a poor example), is that often many `.js` files needs some modified "child" of a "parent" factory. I find it hard to scale my application because `profile.php`, `index.php`, and `editProfile.php` all refer to their own factories and methods, not a base file. Changes, improvements, errors, found in one factory and is corrected, will not propagate into other files (which I find very frustrating). I also don't want to write /copy/paste services and factories over and over again. Other issue I've had is that:

`X.js` file need some providers that `Y.js` file doesn't. However, both needs providers A and B, but X needs `C` and Y needs `D`. Is it bad for me to use the same "factory" and providers" for both of them (i.e. inject A, B, C, and D into both of them?) That's the problem I see with having a base factory of a factory to serve a lot of `.js` files. How much space or inefficiency is it to define providers or injectable services that you don't use?

How do I accomplish some scalable angularJS code to do this, or how do you guys go about organizing your angular code? And also, what about repeating HTML templates (i.e. repeating HTML code that needs to be used in almost every page? I've heard of some service called `$templateCache` but couldn't figure out how to use it.)

Comment: Are these all standalone pages?

Comment: they're all separate `.php` files that link to their own `.js` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide This also has an example app but seriously read through his guidelines they seem to be exactly what you are looking for and have been a great resource for me as I've been learning to build bigger angular apps.

Comment: I've been using parts of this very guide as well. It's been great.